# What is the proper technique for crossing railroad tracks?

Tags: safety, traffic

I cross railroads as perpendicularly as is possible, but that's all I know to do.  Safety is a priority, speed not so much.  Specifically:

- Is there an optimum speed?
- Should you pedal through them or coast?
- Does it depend on the type of bike? (mine is a stock Giant Rapid 3)
- Any other tips?

Comment: If you have a quick release wheel make sure nobody has tampered with it each time you ride. I had someone do that to my bike in high school and had the front wheel come off crossing the tracks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Approach at something close to a right angle.  Easiest if the track is square to the road, of course.  Only a little less easy if the track on the right-hand side (on US roads) is nearer than the left, so you can, in advance of your approach, swing out into the lane to achieve a square approach.  Much trickier the other way -- you must wait for traffic behind to be clear so you can swing out into traffic as you cross.

Approach at "moderate" speed (maybe 10 mph).  For a single track coast, for multiple tracks you likely must crank, but not too hard.

Quite important:  Raise your butt off the seat and "suspend" your body on arms and legs.  This isn't to save your butt (except maybe figuratively) but to assure that the bike doesn't bounce as it goes over the rails, and the wheels maintain firm contact.

As you approach, always study the rails and whatever is placed beside and between the rails.  Often there will be a gap between ends of wood pieces, eg, and you don't want to get your wheel too near that gap.  Very occasionally there will be a splice in the rails themselves, and that likewise needs to be avoided.

And, as one tour leader once told us, if the rails are wet, crawl across, dragging your bike behind you.

Comment: +1 for crawling in the wet. I've only ever had issues on train tracks when it is wet!

Comment: +1 from me as well. A guy I was riding with broke a few ribs riding across wet train tracks. And crossing any tracks at as close to a 90 degree angle as you can manage is always safest.

Comment: what is your opinion on hopping your bike across?

Comment: @robthewolf - Seriously?  I know of a guy who got some non-trivial injuries while attempting something like that.  (I never did figure out exactly what he was trying to do.)  The problem is that even dry tracks are quite slippery, and your tires can squirt out from under you quite unexpectedly.

Comment: Does **crawl** mean "ride really slow" or "walk"?

Comment: @EvanHaas - It means crawl -- on all fours.  Not to be taken quite literally, but one must be very careful if the crossing is wet.  Probably best to walk across.

Comment: +1, this is the good advice for crossing cattle grids too. 90º and bum in the air.

Comment: @PeteH - Thankfully cattle grids are rare around here.  They're like a RR crossing ten times over, except that it's almost safer to ride over than walk, because the footing is so lousy.

Comment: ha, same for me and railroads - they pulled up most of ours in the 1960s to save money. Boy do they regret that one. In fact my house stands on what was once a coalyard. But cattle grids are fine, its all just a case of realising that iron gives crappy traction. Manhole covers in London are worse, plus they seem to deliberately put 'em in bike lanes.

Comment: I've never been wary of crossing railroad tracks, but would like to know if this advice is based on road level crossings, or crossings where the rails are actually on top of the road/trail.  I usually go over tracks at full speed. but the only tracks I go over are road level crossings where the asphalt.

Comment: @Kibbee Up here in Maine we have both (road-level tracks and a-few-inches-above-road-level tracks). Of course the higher ones require you to hop over the extra three inches, but the road level ones have sizable gaps (maybe four inches on either side) enough to grab/twist a front tire. It is really pronounced on slick tires, especially when they're wet. If I can take a picture I'll post it.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon in many parts of the US for a "grade crossing" to be elevated a foot or two above the road on either side, with a relatively steep approach (which is usually poorly paved).  Some such crossings are better crossed on foot.  Around here the crossings are generally "sorta" on grade, but truly smooth crossings are rare on secondary roads.

Answer (score 2):

I stand up and move my weight back so as to unweigh the front wheel. After it has crossed, I move my weight forward and the back wheel does whatever. This helps with acute angle crossing, wet conditions, the tire catching inside the rail grove.

This of course for rails that protrude at most 10cm above the road, not this

[image]